# Is there a way to group GraphQL query fields into sub/nested query groups?

Tags: java, api, graphql, graphql-java

I am using GraphQL-Java and I am new to GraphQL.

I am trying to find a way to organize my API in the same way it's done in the [GraphQL Hub](https://www.graphqlhub.com/playground?query=%23%20Hit%20the%20Play%20button%20above!%0A%23%20Hit%20%22Docs%22%20on%20the%20right%20to%20explore%20the%20API%0A%0A%7B%0A%20%20graphQLHub%0A%20%09reddit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20user(username%3A%20%22kn0thing%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20username%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20commentKarma%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createdISO%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20subreddit(name%3A%20%22movies%22)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20newListings(limit%3A%202)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20username%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09commentKarma%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Essentially, I want to have my RootQuery as the entry point (like the GraphQLHubAPI in the GraphQL Hub) and then sub groups like Reddit, Github etc in the GraphQL Hub)

[image: Inside the RootQuery]

[image: Inside RedditAPI]

I am confused as to what the RedditAPI should be and how I should do the wiring for it. If this is an Object Type, it requires a DataFetcher or some way to resolve request. In their schemas they expose it as [QueryObjectType](https://github.com/clayallsopp/graphqlhub/blob/master/graphqlhub-schemas/src/reddit.js) (using JS)

How can I replicate the same structure using GraphQL-Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the answer is to use a data fetcher that returns a dummy object for the "sub-group" objects. This creates the "path" to your leafs. And you can the handle the leafs in the wiring

For example for the Reddit scenario you can a schema like this

```
schema {
    query: RootQuery
}

type RootQuery {
    RedditAPI: RedditAPI
}

type RedditAPI {
    users: [Users]
    subreddits(name: String!): [subreddit]
}
```

And then wire it up like this

```
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(newTypeWiring("RootQuery")
                        .dataFetcher("RedditAPI", new DataFetcher() {
                            @Override
                            public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) {
                                return RedditAPI.newBuilder().build();
                            }
                        })
                )
                .type(newTypeWiring("RedditAPI")
                        .dataFetcher("users", usersDataFetcher)
                        .dataFetcher("subreddits", subredditsDataFetcher)
                )
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is just return a new Object. Since the default PropertyDataFetcher won't find the fields on the object, it will move on to the declared DataFetchers on your fields:

```
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(newTypeWiring("RootQuery")
                        .dataFetcher("RedditAPI", (environment) -> new Object())
                )
                .type(newTypeWiring("RedditAPI")
                        .dataFetcher("users", usersDataFetcher)
                        .dataFetcher("subreddits", subredditsDataFetcher)
                )
                .build();
```

Comment: How is this not mentioned in the official documentation, the sheer amount of time I have wasted on trying to do this is staggering.

Thanks you Markus.